# how can i track head and eyes in C#.net?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm working on a c# project. What is the best algorithm for head and eye tracking? 
Which one of OpenCVsharp or Emgu.cv is better?  How can I use it in linux?
Is source code available for this?

Comment: Mono can be used to build and run C# applications on Linux.  The other questions are very open ended, and would require subjective responses.  Probably better to do a little more research based on your specific task and then present more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cascade classifier (V&J algorithm) for detecting the face and eyes:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

Then you can track them.

Keep in mind that it will give some noisy detections and works best for profile faces. For frontal faces, you should use the frontal faces cascade (a different xml).